# When I try to compile the following code in Arduino ,I get the error "expected initializer before 'void'".How can I get the code to work?

Tags: arduino-uno

When I try to compile the following code in Arduino ,I get the error "expected initializer before 'void'".How can I get the code to work?

```
const int LED = 9;
const int BUTON = 2


void setup() {
  pinMode (LED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (BUTON, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(BUTON) == HIGH);
  {
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is actually not an Arduino related problem. Everybody that gets into physical computing should have some basic knowledge in C/C++ and the compiling of such code. Using an Arduino on top of that adds complexity and is more difficult to debug if something does not work as intended. So I hereby encourage you to take some tutorials in writing C/C++ to get a feeling of all the traps that lurk at you along your journey.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a semi-colon after `const int BUTON = 2`

Each expression should be terminated with a semi-colon.  Your code should look like this:

```
const int LED = 9;
const int BUTON = 2;


void setup() {
  pinMode (LED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (BUTON, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(BUTON) == HIGH)
  {
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
  }
}
```